# Recursive insert-method for a linked list

Tags: c#, .net

I'm learning C# and I've made a recursive insert-method for a linked list:

```
public static int recursiveInsert(ref int value, ref MyLinkedList list) {
    if (list == null)
        return new MyLinkedList(value, null);
    else {
        list.next = recursiveInsert(ref int value, ref list.next);
        return list;
    }
}
```

How can I modify this method to make the recursive call look like this:

```
recursiveInsert(value, ref list.next)
```

instead of:

```
list.next = recursiveInsert(ref int value, ref list.next);
```

Comment: but why you need "ref value" if noone changes it inside the method, so noone would even read that "changed" value after the call?

Comment: Your return signature and your `return` statements don't all match up.

Comment: Pass the list by ref and the `value` as the return value of the function. Also, this will cause a Stackoverflow exception since you never stop recursing.

Comment: @Gusman It won't create a new list each time a value is added because if the value is added the list is not null thus no new list will be made.

Comment: Don't you just wanna add a node instead of a linkedlist?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C# 5, it would be written exactly the same in C# 1.

Comment: No, I'm not completly sure about what I'm doing. Like I said, I'm learining :). The original intention was to make a standalone recursive insert function (not part of MyLinkedList) that takes the node and a pointer as reference parameters.

Comment: @user3726477 And other than having the wrong return type of your method, you've done just that.  Your method should work just fine after that small error is fixed.  All uses of `ref` everywhere are superflous, and should really be removed, but adding them doesn't *break* the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are never actually mutating the parameters that you are passing by reference, you can just not pass them by reference at all.  You need to recognize that `MyLinkedList` being a reference type (it should absolutely be a reference type) means that you're not passing the value of the object itself, you're passing a reference to it, so you can mutate that reference without passing the reference by reference.)  Just remove all uses of `ref` (and also fix your return type to be correct) and you're just done:

```
public static MyLinkedList recursiveInsert(int value, MyLinkedList list)
{
    if (list == null)
        return new MyLinkedList(value, null);
    else
    {
        list.next = recursiveInsert(value, list.next);
        return list;
    }
}
```